# How long it takes for new cryptographic results to become generally accepted?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography

Suppose there is a new scheme, for the sake of argument let's call it a CEPQSS - CryptoEnthusiast's Post-Quantum Signature Scheme. Now most practitioners aren't convinced that using this is a good idea let alone that it works. But the results are completely valid.

How long would it take until most practitioners evaluate and peer review it to the point where it would be generally accepted?

Comment: "But the results are completely valid."; what does that mean?  That there are no feasible attacks against the system?  How does anyone know that?

Comment: The result appears invalid at first sight but is actually robust in face of any attack yes

Comment: @poncho This is just more spam about "haircomb".  It seemed to start this morning.

Comment: While this question does read like a request for validation of the "haircomb" scheme that has stirred things up a bit lately, I think it's a valid enough question to ask - especially considering the context of the scheme which is why (for now at least) I see no reason to remove / mod-close this question. Also I'm actually surprised that a variant of this question seems to not have popped up yet (or at least I couldn't find it).

Comment: I have changed the name of the "hypothetical" scheme in question to be something more neutral. It may be noteworthy to answerers that the original name had an association with one which was published as a text file on Github, with potential analysis on bitcointalk.

Answer (score 6):

> How long would it take until most practitioners evaluate and peer review it [...]?

Unfortunately peer review tends to be more of a "push" than a "pull" based process. Meaning that experts in that area tend not to crawl the internet for schemes to investigate and "declare good to use" but rather that the authors of such schemes work hard to get that attention. And even then, most schemes - even those with somewhat famous authors - have excellent chances at never being used seriously in practice. This is the case even if the relevant people have used much of their time to analyse such proposals and found no flaws.

The best example for this is actually the on-going NIST Post-Quantum Competition where chances are really slim for any candidate kicked out in the third round to see any real usage.

So even if a scheme is good - and it has to be reasonably secure and performant - *and* it is published in the right place at the right time with a large amount of serious, convincing self-analysis, there's a good chance that it never sees real usage outside of that the author implements themself.

This situation doesn't get better if the scheme in question has no properly formatted paper with lots of relevant, convincing cryptanalysis and security proofs, which hasn't even been submitted / accepted at the right venue / journal.

If one would *really* want to have such initial analysis it might be worth to try and hire a serious, professional cryptographer as a consultant and either have them analyse the scheme - which is unlikely to be very useful given that this kind of work takes a lot of time and thus money - or to collect (some) likely relevant initial background material to start working on the analysis in a way that is generally accepted. Additionally such professional help would likely also be able to review the analysis to give potential improvement suggestions to the analysis and its presentation to lessen the chance of an instant reject if and when it is tried to be submitted to a serious venue.

Comment: Addition: if the scheme is covered by a patent that's not explicitly licensed for free, that decreases the chances that it gets used even if it is academically recognized. That happened to the Schnorr signature scheme.